Ubuntu 24.04 not loading after login
I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 a few weeks ago, but already like 1 week everything was running smoothly. And while I was doing some upgrades (mostly reinstalling CUDA, Nvidia driver, and some new conda envs, also playing around with the keyboard layout - Czech and Korean) the PC got stuck and nothing was working really - like no keyboard commands. I have turned off the PC and turned it on (just with the physical button).
Now I am in this situation when it loads up to Login screen, I put my password and it breaks.

Right after Login I get this screen.

Then after sometime it turns into this. So you can see that some apps are running (conky and the notes), but not normal Ubuntu screen.


What I have tried so far.

From here: Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't load GUI and login screen after Upgrade from 23.10 I tried systemctl status gdm but I got this message

so I guess this part is ok? Or not? Because I found here How to solve: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file?  that is is just informational message, not error.

And from this Unable to login to Ubuntu 24.04 I have tried to change my password, but it didn't help either.

I tried running dpkg -l | grep ^..r and dpkg-query -W -f='${db:Status-Abbrev} ${binary:Package}\n' | grep -E ^.[^nci] and dpkg -C to see if anything is broken, but it didn't show me anything... Also, sudo apt update + sudo apt upgrade run without showing any error.

I tried running sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^ as suggested in the comments
but I personally didn't see any error after the installation finished, so I tried to reboot the PC and still the same error.


Thank you for any advice!

Run the command sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^. Does it help?

@ArchismanPanigrahi I tried it, but still the same result... I will edit the original post with the screen, I personally don't see any error, but you might.

I cannot spot an error either. Sorry

So, this actually happened again to me on my other PC and I have figured out where was the problem, why the error happened and how to fix it.
Why did it happen
The error happened after installing sudo apt install fcitx-hangul because I wanted to get a proper Korean keyboard (taken advice from here).
How to fix it
So, I used these to uninstall fcitx-hangul:

sudo apt purge fcitx-hangul
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
reboot

How to add Korean keyboard
I have managed to add Korean keyboard through this guide
